# sed/awk: replace numbers in a line after last occurance of '.'

Tags: awk, sed, tcpdump, numeric-data

I have the following tcpdump stream:

```
Current:
07:36:03.848461 IP 172.17.3.41.33101 > 172.17.3.43.17408: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848463 IP 172.17.3.42.33101 > 172.17.3.43.17409: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-A.33101 > 172.17.3.43.17418: UDP, length 45
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-B.33101 > 172.17.3.43.17419: UDP, length 45
```

The port numbers are in decimal. How can I pipe it to sed or awk to modify the stream so its the same stream with the port numbers changed to hexademical:

```
Expected:
07:36:03.848461 IP 172.17.3.41.814d > 172.17.3.43.4400: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848463 IP 172.17.3.42.814d > 172.17.3.43.4401: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-A.814d > 172.17.3.43.440a: UDP, length 45
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-B.814d > 172.17.3.43.440b: UDP, length 45
```

If I have the port number, I use this to convert it into hexadecimal:

```
echo 33101 | sed  -e 's/.*://' | xargs printf "%x\n"
814d
```

I have been trying to solve this but no luck. How can I replace the port numbers after the last occurrence of `'.'` in the third and fifth column of the stream and then change it to hexadecimal on the fly?

Comment: Are those numbers always in the same fields, here: $3 and $5?

Comment: @RudiC yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If field numbers are constant - as in your question fields 3 and 5 - try

```
awk '
function CHX(FLD)   {n = split ($FLD, T, ".")
                     sub (T[n] "$", sprintf ("%X", T[n]), $FLD)
                    }
    {CHX(3)
     CHX(5)
    }
1
' file
07:36:03.848461 IP 172.17.3.41.814D > 172.17.3.43.4400 UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848463 IP 172.17.3.42.814D > 172.17.3.43.4401 UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-A.814D > 172.17.3.43.440A UDP, length 45
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-B.814D > 172.17.3.43.440B UDP, length 45
```

For e.g. a trailing colon in field 5:

```
awk '
function CHX(FLD)       {n = split ($FLD, T, "[^0-9]")
                         TRM = ""
                         if (!T[n])     {n--
                                         TRM = substr ($FLD, length($FLD))
                                        }
                         sub (T[n] TRM "$", sprintf ("%X%s", T[n], TRM), $FLD)
                        }
        {CHX(3)
         CHX(5)
        }
1
' file
```

Comment: I see - corrected the first of your observations...

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\s\S+\.\K\d+/sprintf "%x", $&/ge' < your-file
```

That looks for words consisting of a whitespace (`\s`) followed by a *sequence of one or more* (`+`) *non-whitespace* (`\S`), a dot and a sequence of one or more digits (`\d+`) and replaces the end part (whose start is marked with `\K`) with the same (`$&`) formatted in he`x`adecimal (`g`lobally, the replacement being `e`valuated as perl code).

Answer (score 1):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function mkPortHex(fldNr,       port, sfx) {
    port = sfx = $fldNr
    sub(/.*\./,"",port)
    sub(/.*[0-9]/,"",sfx)
    sub(/[^.]+$/,sprintf("%x%s",port,sfx),$fldNr)
}
{
    mkPortHex(3)
    mkPortHex(5)
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
07:36:03.848461 IP 172.17.3.41.814d > 172.17.3.43.4400: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848463 IP 172.17.3.42.814d > 172.17.3.43.4401: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-A.814d > 172.17.3.43.440a: UDP, length 45
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-B.814d > 172.17.3.43.440b: UDP, length 45
```

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
function mkPortHex(fldNr) {
    match($fldNr,/(.*\.)([0-9]+)(:?)/,a)
    $fldNr = a[1] sprintf("%x",a[2]) a[3]
}
{
    mkPortHex(3)
    mkPortHex(5)
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
07:36:03.848461 IP 172.17.3.41.814d > 172.17.3.43.4400: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848463 IP 172.17.3.42.814d > 172.17.3.43.4401: UDP, length 44
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-A.814d > 172.17.3.43.440a: UDP, length 45
07:36:03.848467 IP SYSTEM-B.814d > 172.17.3.43.440b: UDP, length 45
```

Comment: *any awk* should probably by *any modern awk*, i.e. not the original `awk` like the `/bin/awk` of Solaris which didn't have functions. On Solaris, one would need to use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead though I suppose most Solaris users would already be aware the utilities in `/bin` are unusable.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but old, broken awk (the unfortunate default on Solaris and the only one the script wouldn't work in) doesn't need to be explicitly excluded from every conversation. It's old, broken and should never be used and if you were going to consider it you'd have to state it as an exception in almost every answer. Fortunately almost every time you do try to use it you'll get the `syntax error at line` error message it invariably produces and so there's a quick warning you're on the wrong track.

Comment: I agree with that, but then if you're saying _With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box_, you're asking for that comment. Just say _with any modern awk_ or _any standard awk_ (the UNIX in all uppercase kind of implies that you're talking UNIX(TM) systems, i.e. Solaris/AIX/macOS and the other ones certified by the OpenGroup. Unix or UNIX-like systems have less chance or being interpreted that way).

Comment: Again, I get where you're coming from but IMHO we need to just lay old, broken awk to rest and not let it influence our answers in **any way**. The answer I posted won't only work in any modern or any standard awk, it'll even work with non-POSIX awk versions from the 1980s such as nawk, mawk, and tawk, it just (in common with most scripts) won't work with old, broken awk. All I could really say other than "any awk" is "any awk except old, broken awk" and again, in my opinion, we shouldn't have to keep stating that as a caveat when it's almost always true and no-one should ever use that awk.

Answer (score 0):

First one should ask if this is sensible, having `172.17.3.43.440a` where the first 4 period separated fields are decimal and the 5th is hex looks odd. However let us assume the OP has good reasons.

The OP gave us some sample data and desired output, this is **very** helpful.

The OP shows us `echo 33101 | sed  -e 's/.*://' | xargs printf "%x\n"` which gives us some insight into their thought processes. This tells me they are on the wrong track. They want to break up the line somehow (using `awk` or `sed` based on the tags), use `printf` to convert it to hex, and then reassemble the line. Repeat for each line. Whilst obviously this could to be made to work, it is very slow. Unix and Linux processes are cheap, but not free. This approach will use many processes per line, and a tcpdump stream output can be expected to have many hundreds of lines. It is desirable to do the change using only a few processes per **file** so this has reasonable speed if at all possible.

So on to the choice of tool. The tags suggest `sed` and `awk`. I would reject `sed`. It is `turing complete` (assuming infinite amount of memory) and so can do anything that can be done in any other language, but that doesn't mean to say it is going to be easy or readable. If I was doing this I would probably reach for `perl` or `python`, but `awk` is perfectly reasonable, so let us use that.

`awk` programs loop over lines by themselves, so this is a good start. The OP talks about the `third column` but looking at the desired output they also want the fifth one as well. They don't want the milliseconds in the first column converted to hex, although that also is a number `after last occurrence of '.'`. So there is a choice to be made, do we loop over each of the columns (called "fields" in awk) after the first or do we just do the third and fifth? Either would work. Let us take the general case and do all the columns. This give us

```
    for(f=2;f<NF;f++){
       # do something with field f
    }
```

Now we need to see if the field matches a `.` followed by a number and then an optional `:` (so we convert the 5th field in the original data). This can be done with a regular expression, one of the powerful ideas that Unix popularized.

```
    for(f=2;f<NF;f++){
       if ($f ~ /\.[0-9][0-9]*:?$/) {
           # this field needs to be converted
       }
    }
```

So now to do the conversion. Use `match` to break apart the pattern, and sprintf to put it back, to get the final program

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
   for(f=2;f<NF;f++){
       if ($f ~ /\.[0-9][0-9]*:?$/) {
           match($f,/^(.*\.)([0-9][0-9]*)(:?)$/,a)
           $f=sprintf("%s%x%s",a[1],a[2],a[3])
       }
    }
    print
}
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers! All of them work! However I would like to post my solution here as well. Now I know that I specifically asked for `sed` and `awk` for this but my input is a `tcpdump` stream and I wanted to modify the port numbers to hexadecimal. So I went through the source code and changed the following lines:

[`(void)snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%u", i);`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/0a963390e5c109d62456cc9c9119d2bf111616a9/addrtoname.c#L752)

to

```
(void)snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%x", i); // prints hexadecimal
```

[`(void)snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%u", i);`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/0a963390e5c109d62456cc9c9119d2bf111616a9/addrtoname.c#L774)

to

```
(void)snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%x", i); // prints hexadecimal
```

Compiled the binary and now tcpdump prints the ports in hexadecimal.